# How fast is the Female Titan?

Tags: attack-on-titan

In season 1 episode 12, we see The Female titan give chase to the Special Operations Squad and Eren. We also know that the horses to bred to run at 70-75 mph per hour, but it was shown late that the female titan sped up and was about to catch them before they ran past the traps set for her. So what speed does she run at if she's faster than the horses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd like to think that the Female Titan is probably the fastest among the 9 titans in terms of running speed and not agility (in which case I think the Jaw Titan would dominate). Here's the explanation. The Female Titan managed to outrun the Scout Regiment Horses as seen throughout the "Female Titan Arc" and she even managed to catch up from the Right Wing up to the Rear of the Center whilst the entire platoon is CONSTANTLY moving at the speed of the said horses. Deducing from all the information above she has to be about twice as fast as the horses in order to catch up to Levi Squad by the end of the episode, also putting into consideration all the scout members' attempt to slow her down (fighting her and delaying her movement).

Now let's compare her to the other fast shifters such as the Cart Titan and the Jaw Titan, let's start with what we have seen. The Jaw Titan may be very agile and nimble but when running in the anime, I don't think she even comes close to the Female Titan. She tried to catch up to Connie riding his horse while he took Christa (not revealing her true name) and yet she never caught up. Meaning she has to be at the same speed with the horses.

Moving on to the Cart Titan. The anime didn't really shown much about its speed but it i notably very fast too considering it saved the beast titan holder from certain death. But they didn't note how fast it was meaning it's not that impressive. Unlike how Armin, recognized the Female Titan's unbelievable speed during her first appearance.

So there you go, maybe among the 3 Fast Titan Shifters I'd rank them like this:

1.) Female Titan (Actual facts from wiki and the anime)
2.) Cart Titan (From the wiki and bits of hints from the anime.)
3.) Jaw Titan (From observation)

Comment: Please include relevant sources/references. Do not just say 'from the anime' or 'from the manga'. Indicate specific episodes or chapters if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Its never told in the manga how fast is every titan, what is the maximum speed of every titan. but there are another 2 titan that have high speed `Cart Titan` and `Jaw Titan`, yeah these two are part of `Nine Titan` just like `Female Titan`.